# Reducibility over a certain field.

Tags: field-theory

Let $K=F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$. I want to show that $f(x)=x^4+x^2+1$ is reducible over $K$ but has no roots in it. How to proceed? I know that $F$ contains 8 elements, how is the structure of these elements? How can I realize the elements of this field?

Comment: Excuse me, what is $F$? Do you mean $K$?

Comment: Note that $f(x)=x^4+x^2+1$ is reducible over $F_2$, it is a square.

Comment: That's what I have to show, to split it as two factors of degree 2.

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar, you should know the property of the map $a \mapsto a^2$ in characteristic 2.

Comment: yes $x^4+x^2+1$ is the square of $x^2+x+1$ in $F_2$

Comment: Great, @WaqasAliAzhar, you are nearly there. Now note that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $F_2[x]$, and so is $x^3+x+1$, so that $\lvert K : F_2 \rvert = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find all quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ and find
two of which that when multiplied, and using $x^{3}+x+1\equiv0$,
gives you $f$.